# How to have different header h2 in each page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having a problem with the header text in wordpress. I need to make different header h2 for each page. I don't know much about php.

I created a new header2.php with the different h2 and then I put this code in my header.php:

```
if (is_page( 'GŁÓWNA' ) ) { 
    get_header( 'header2.php' );
}
```

but it's not working at all, nothing changed. It cannot find the path as well. Where should I write this condition? Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks madforstrength, now finally it's working, but it's showing me both header  in 'GŁÓWNA' page. one under the other. What to do to see just one?

Answer (score 0):

Refer https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header

When you write like below:

```
<?php
if ( is_home() ) :
    get_header( 'home' );
elseif ( is_404() ) :
    get_header( '404' );
else :
    get_header();
endif;
?>
```

Then the file name should be like header-home.php and header-404.php.

Comment: Thanks...!! @NanaPartykar

Answer (score 0):

You cant give file name in get_header() function 
You need to change your filename to something like `header-header2.php` and than use this:

```
if (is_page( 'GŁÓWNA' ) ) { 
    get_header( 'header2' );
}else {
    get_header();
}
```

Comment: Thanks madforstrength, now finally it's working, but it's showing me both header in 'GŁÓWNA' page. one under the other. What to do to see just one?

Comment: @ppp in your page where you added `get_header('header2')` you will also find `get_header()` this should go in else condition

Answer (score 0):

create second header like

```
header-header2.php
```

and then call like this (Look at this concept [click here](http://icode4you.net/wordpress-create-and-use-a-second-header-php-file/))

```
if(is_page( 'GŁÓWNA' ) ){
   get_header( 'header2' );
}else{
   get_header();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working now but it's showing me both header in 'GŁÓWNA' page, one under the other. What can I do to see just header2?

Comment: `GŁÓWNA` page avaliable or not please first check it